# xml.etree.ElementTree in Python (3.x) is not parsing one particular attribute value

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing

The data file testfile.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body>
  <body.head>
    <hedline>
      <hl1 style="header">All the things we lost that summer</hl1>
      <hl2 style="standfirst">It was the promise of seals that sold Virginia on this mission.</hl2>
      <hl2 style="dropcap-large"><em class="dropcap">W</em>e are always calling each other names.</hl2>
    </hedline>
  </body.head>
</body>
```

The script to parse this file is this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('testfile.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
if root.find('body.head') is not None:
    if root.find('body.head').find('hedline') is not None:
        for child1 in root.find('body.head').find('hedline'):
            print("Tag    level 1:" + child1.tag)
            print("Attrib level 1:" + str(child1.attrib))
            print("Text   level 1:" + str(child1.text) + "\n")
            for child2 in child1:
                print("Tag    level 2:" + child2.tag)
                print("Attrib level 2:" + str(child2.attrib))
                print("Text   level 2:" + str(child2.text))
```

And this is the result:

```
Tag    level 1:hl1
Attrib level 1:{'style': 'header'}
Text   level 1:All the things we lost that summer

Tag    level 1:hl2
Attrib level 1:{'style': 'standfirst'}
Text   level 1:It was the promise of seals that sold Virginia on this mission.

Tag    level 1:hl2
Attrib level 1:{'style': 'dropcap-large'}
Text   level 1:None  <-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM

Tag    level 2:em
Attrib level 2:{'class': 'dropcap'}
Text   level 2:W
```

I would expect the report line "Text   level 1:" to report the value "e are always calling each other names." from the data file, but instead it cannot parse it so it ends up being None.
Can you perhaps parse it correctly?
This is Python 3.12 on Windows.

Thanks, Martijn

Comment: The text "in" that element is not where you think it is.  Part of it is in the text nodes of the `<em>`, and the rest is in a text node _after_ the `<em>`.  You must always handle the situation of multiple text nodes, there's never a guarantee that all text "inside" an element is in one piece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because in ElementTree (and lxml), "e are always calling each other names." is the `.tail` of the `em` element.

The `.text` property only includes the first text node that is before any other child elements. In this case, there are none.

See [`tail` here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail) for more info.